# Proper naming query

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

i have naming problems with two of my functions

- i've got a function `is_void` that returns true if the argument is "empty" (in some sense). How would you call an opposite function? `isnt_void`? `is_set`? `is_not_void`?
- i have a pair of functions, the first one installs a handler to catch errors in the subsequent code and the second removes this handler. `install_error_handler/remove_error_handler` looks too long and ugly, i'd prefer a pair of short verbs (like watch/unwatch).

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the answers so far

**UPDATED:** I need a function for "isn't void" because it's going to be used like `someArray.map(is_not_void)`

the second one cannot be simply "register" or "install", because it's used without arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, try to (1) minimize the number of interface functions and (2) provide precise and consistent names.

In the case of naming the `not is_void()` case, the first principle tells us to not have the function exist at all since the user can always negate the boolean return.  In other words, `is_void()` is a constraint checking function, it is up to the caller to decide to explicitly negate the constraint as necessary.

The `install_...` and `remove_...` case is where the second principle applies.  The problem with short verbs is that they are very ambiguous but it is not always possible to remove ambiguity through naming.  What is most important is that they are as descriptive as possible and that you apply some consistent method.  If you use `watch_...` and `unwatch_...`, use them consistently.  Don't have `watch_errors` alongside `observe_warnings`.  The inconsistency will cause users to look for reasons for the naming difference.

Personally, I prefer `install_..._handler` and `uninstall_..._handler` or `add_observer` with a filter condition over `watch_condition` and `unwatch_condition` simply because *unwatch* does not look like a *real word* to my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure why you need a different function for #1; if it's not void, then is_void would return false.

For #2, if you're passing an error handler into the method; Install/Uninstall should be sufficient.

Comment: Cool, I'm still not completely sold on #1; couldn't you do something like this:  someArray.map(!is_void())

As for 2; i think you're stuck with install/remove_error_handler

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question: as a rule, I avoid negatives in function names. Something like:

```
IsNotVoid( String s )
```

may seem harmless enough, but invariably, you're going to do something like

```
if ( ! IsNotVoid( s ) && ! IsNotVoid( t ) )
{
}
```

... which is going to make the next programmer think way too hard for not being able to immediately discern your intent.

Answer (score 1):

The test functions are a good idea.  However, I'd warn against using negative naming because that invites double (or more) negative logic `if (not is_not_void(a))`.  A simple not operator should suffice:  `if (not is_void(a))`.

Answer (score 1):

From your update I assume you mean you need a pointer to the method. I always try to use names to be as clear as possible, so I would ask myself first what the meaning of `is_void` is. From your text I would propose `is_empty`, `is_not_set` or `is_nothing` instead of `is_void` the opposites could be `is_not_empty`, `is_set` or `is_something`, the last one sound a bit funny but would probably come close to the meaning in your code.

I don't think you have to guard against overly verbose naming, you have to watch out for overly terse naming as that often is a source for ambiguity.

As for the `install_error_handler` and `uninstall_error_handler`, if these names describe the purpose correctly I would keep them. If not try to describe what their meaning is in terms of your code (guard, protect, lock...)